# how to choose LSTM 2-d input shape?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to feed 1-D signal(1,2000) which has 22 features(22,2000) into LSTM.
(1-D signal is taken by 10 seconds with 200 hz sampling rate)
And I have 808 batches. (808, 22, 2000)

I saw that the LSTM receives 3D tensor shape of (batch_size, timestep, input_dim).
So is it right that my input shape as?
: (batch_size = 808, timestep = 2000, input_dim = 3)

here is my sample of code.

```python
# data shape check
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
(727, 22, 2000)
(81, 22, 2000)
(727, 2)
(81, 2)

# Model Config
inputshape = (808,2000,2)  # 22 chanel, 2000 samples
lstm_1_cell_num = 20
lstm_2_cell_num = 20
inputdrop_ratio = 0.2
celldrop_ratio = 0.2

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_1_cell_num, input_shape=inputshape, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_2_cell_num, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: You don’t include batch size in the input shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First input shape must be (22,2000) and batch size should be given in the fit function. So try this

```
inputshape = (22,2000)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=808,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
          shuffle=True)
```

Comment: i found it in keras.io, rnn's output shape should be like this 'if return_sequences: 3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, units).'. So i guess it should be (2000,22).